# Посчитать проценты JS

Tags: арифметика

У меня есть две переменных

```
let valMax = 29
let valNow = 15
let valEnter = ?
```

переменная *valMax* не меняется,
переменная *valNow* всегда меняется

в переменную *valEnter* мне нужно вывести результат в проценте,
**Как объяснить Джаваскрипту что 29 это 100%**

Comment: Поделить на 29 и умножить на 100.

Comment: https://skysmart.ru/articles/mathematic/procent-chisla-ot-chisla

Answer (score 3):

самое простое -

```
100 * текущее / максимальное
```

вообще общая формула

```
100 * (current - min) / (max - min)
```

а с учетом границ и невозможности их преодоления (в некоторых случаях не должно быть больше 100% и меньше 0%)

```
(current < min) ? 0 : (current > max) ? 100 : (100 * (current - min) / (max - min))
```

Answer (score 2):

Неужели в школах нынче так плохо учат?

```
Если
x = a
y = b
То
x*b = a*y
```

или как у вас

```
29 = 100%
15 = x%

x = 100*15/29 %
```